# How to create a SQL column whose values depend on (map to) the values of an existing lookup column?

Tags: sql, mapping, rename

A simplified version of what I'm asking is: Say I already have a column for pedestrian jacket colors and it is very specific includes values like (canary, gold, dandelion, yellow, lemonade, sky blue, baby blue, cerulean, etc.). I want to create 2 new columns:
"Color Group" and "Light-Dark" so that I can label all of the yellow-ish jackets under Color Group yellow and I can classify all of them as light colors.

Please note that I'm working within a database product and all of the data is stored in the database I cannot create new data within the actual database. But in the reporting module, I can create columns based on existing columns. This data would only exist in the report and not in the database. Also, the way its set up I don't need the SELECT command that just happens by default but feel free to put it in your response it won't confuse me.
I've tried:

if 
customer_jacket_color = "dandelion"
then
"Yellow"

Also tried it with WHEN instead of "if"

when customer_jacket_color_group = 'Yellow' 
   then
'light'

My expected results would take the 1 column of colors and give me 3 columns that describe the colors based on how I map the original values to the new columns. 
Dandelion, Yellow, Light
Navy Blue, Blue, Dark
Mint, Green, Light...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case when customer_jacket_color = 'dandelion' then 'Yellow'
             when customer_jacket_color = 'sky blue' then 'Blue'
             . . .
        end) as color_group,
       (case when customer_jacket_color = 'dandelion' then 'light'
             when customer_jacket_color = 'sky blue' then 'dark'
             . . .
        end) as light_dark
from t;
```

Comment: I think you could use the `case customer_jacket_color when ...` format.

Comment: @avery_larry . . . I am guessing that the OP might find `IN` or `LIKE` to be useful for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks. The first response worked well! This was my first post and am finding this resource extremely helpful as I begin developing my coding skills.

Comment: @TSmith . . . You can consider accepting the answer, if it answers your question.

Comment: @Gordon thanks like I mentioned new to this, I actually had to Google how to accept answer LOL. Solution worked well.